# ASP.net JSON Rest API Output from Complex Class from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, rest, asp.net-web-api

Database Tables

```
tbl_Product
 - id (pk)
 - name
 - price
tbl_image
 - id (pk)
 - prd_id (fk)
 - imageUrl
```

I want to the Json result from my database like this

```json
[
   {
      "id":"",
      "name":"",
      "price":"",
      "images":[
         {
            "id":"",
            "imageUrl":""
         },
         {
            "id":"",
            "imageUrl":""
         },
         {
            "id":"",
            "imageUrl":""
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"",
      "name":"",
      "price":"",
      "images":[
         {
            "id":"",
            "imageUrl":""
         },
         {
            "id":"",
            "imageUrl":""
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

C# Object Class

```
class ProductModel
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string price {get; set;}
   public ImageModel images {get; set;}
}

class ImageModel
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public int prd_id {get; set;}
   public string imageUrl {get; set;}
}
```

First of all i would like to thank you for reading my simple question.

How to get json output like above ..
I am confused if i join  the query to get the output like this ..

```
 select *  from tbl_Product a inner join tbl_images b on a.id = b.prd_id
```

This will result join the two tables, How do i separate it out from Business logic to generate that output ..

or

Do we need to GetAllProduct from tbl_Product table and do for loop and while mapping datatable to object fetch imageByProductId and add to that ProductModel Object ..

I am not sure is this the fastest way .. i don;t want to use entity framework ...
I want just a method which provide me JSON in above format and try to make sure the method is in C# without any framework

Thank you for reading my question and waiting for your ans.

Comment: images is plural and let me think about a collection and not a single instance. Can you clarify?

Comment: Basically i want to generated data output like above .. 
I have two tables 
product table is dependent on image table . 
So Please suggest me a way what kind of Query to Database will be and to generate output like this ..

Comment: You mention you don't want to use EF. So what technology do you use to fed the model?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your models need to be like this

```
    class ProductModel
    {
       public int id {get; set;}
       public string name {get; set;}
       public string price {get; set;}
       public IList<ImageModel> images {get; set;}
    }

    class ImageModel
    {
       public int id {get; set;}
       public string imageUrl {get; set;}
    }
```

and then try below linq to sql query

```
    tbl_Product.Select(prod => 
         new ProductModel
            { 
                   id = prod.id,
                   name = prod.name,
                   price = prod.price,
                   images = prod.tbl_image.Select(img => new ImageModel
                                           {
                                              id = img.id,
                                              imageUrl = img.imageUrl
                                            })

            }).ToList()
```

Comment: FYI: Vladimir is using LINQ to SQL there, so make sure you know how to use it.

Comment: @Vladimir thank you but i am having very less experience working with linq.

And also i want the solution that to be performance wise better because my product table hold the 1M+ records ..

Comment: BTW i tried one quick thing ..

Fetch All data from Product and Fetch All Data from Images Stored in List objects and iterate among the Image List and find the matching record and if true push that record to Product list ...

That give the same result but not sure if that the proper and fastest way ..

Comment: @MayankJhawar from performance point of view this linq query is pretty fast, eventually it sends only one sql to database and receives all data due one request to database, so no additional connections to database, if you do not want to drill into linq staff and create Context, models, etc..,  you can use ADO.net

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Azure SQL Database or you can install SQL Server 2016 then you can add FOR JSON AUTO clause:

```
select *  from tbl_Product a inner join tbl_images b on a.id = b.prd_id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This would return you JSON text that you can simply return as response of API.